# create new array with similar key

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, angular8, ngfor

i have an array like this:

```
subjectWithTopics = [
  {subjectName:"maths", topicName : "topic1 of maths " },
  {subjectName:"maths", topicName : "topic2 of maths " },
  {subjectName:"English", topicName : "topic1 of English " },
  {subjectName:"English", topicName : "topic2 of English " },
  {subjectName:"English", topicName : "topic3 of English " },
]
```

What i want is to loop through this array like this using *ngFor in angular :

- maths:

  topic 1 of maths

  topic 2 of maths
- English

  topic 1 of english

  topic 2 of english

  topic 3 of english

Desired array:

```
subjectWithTopics =[
{"SubjectName" : "Maths",
        "topicName" : [
          {
            topic1 of maths
          },
          {
           topic 2 of maths
          },
        ]
},
 {"SubjectName" : "English",
        "topicName" : [
          {
            topic 1 of English
          },
          {
            topic 2 of English
          },
          {
            topic 3 of English
          }
        ]
}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be easily done with the help of [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method:

**ts**

```
subjectWithTopics = [
  { subjectName: "maths", topicName: "topic1 of maths " },
  { subjectName: "maths", topicName: "topic2 of maths " },
  { subjectName: "English", topicName: "topic1 of English " },
  { subjectName: "English", topicName: "topic2 of English " },
  { subjectName: "English", topicName: "topic3 of English " },
];

desiredResult: { SubjectName: string; topics: any[] }[];

ngOnInit() {
  const groups = this.subjectWithTopics.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    (acc[cur.subjectName] = acc[cur.subjectName] || []).push(cur.topicName);

    return acc;
  }, {});
  this.desiredResult = Object.keys(groups).map(key => ({ SubjectName: key, topics: groups[key] }))
}
```

**html**

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of desiredResult">
  <li>
    {{ item.SubjectName }}
    <ol>
      <li *ngFor="let topic of item.topics">
        {{ topic }}
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/sNs0nykCPvZI9JQ36oUt?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**